# Comparing Arrays and Creating Directories

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm probably in over my head here. I'm trying to create a bash script that will identify files beginning with 5 digits, check if a directory exists for that matching file (or group of files) and move the files into the directory. If the directory doesn't exist, I want to create it, then move the files.

This is the script as I've gotten so far, but realistically it isn't far at all.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=($(find . -type f | grep -E "[0-9]{5}" -o))
directories=($(find . -type d))

for i in ${files[*]}
do
  printf "▸ ▸ pdf file found: %s\n" $i
done

for d in ${directories[*]}
do
 printf "▸ ▸ directory found: %s\n" $d
done

NewDir=(`echo ${files[@]} ${directories[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u `)

for nd in ${NewDir[*]}
do
  printf "mkdir for: %s\n" $nd
done
```

Example of a directory that needs to be sorted would look like this:

```
476B Oct 19 14:43 .
544B Oct 21 10:36 ..
 68B Sep 17 08:14 12345/
 68B Sep 17 08:14 12735/
  0B Sep 17 08:14 29375.pdf
  0B Sep 17 08:14 29375a.pdf
  0B Sep 17 08:14 29375-1.pdf
  0B Sep 17 08:14 32952.pdf
  0B Sep 17 08:14 39472.pdf
 68B Sep 17 08:14 59723/
  0B Sep 17 08:14 97132.pdf
273B Oct 19 14:43 sort.sh
```

So going off of this example, I want to identify the files beginning with 29375 and make a directory for them, then move them into that directory.

This is where I run into trouble, comparing the files that are found, with the directories that exist. The NewDir array was a test I was doing when I was trying to search for a solution to this.

Thanks in advanced for the feedback/help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this does the job, with no need of using arrays:

```
for dir in $(find -E . -type f -regex ".*/[[:digit:]]{5}.*" \
              | sed -E 's@\./([0-9]{5}).*@\1@' | sort -u) ; do 
    if [ ! -d "$dir" ] ; then
        mkdir "$dir"
    fi
    if [ ! -d "$dir" ] ; then
        continue
    fi
    find -E . -type f -regex ".*/$dir.*" -exec mv \{\} $dir \;
done
```

Depending on the number of directories, you may need to convert this to using a `while` loop consuming the output of `find -E . -type f -regex ".*/[[:digit:]]{5}.*" | sed -E 's@\./([0-9]{5}).*@\1@' | sort -u`, as in its current form the latter may exceed an acceptable length.

EDIT: Note that `-regex` is actually a gnu find extension so it will only work when GNU find is the first `find` found on the PATH

Comment: Thank you. Trying to figure out what sed is doing but besides that the script is doing something rather odd. Testing the find command on it's own, produces the correct results. However when the if statements check for $dir, it uses the whole file name (with extensions) instead of the results of the find command on it's own. After adding some printf for debugging this happens:

Files found: ./11111-1.jpg
Checking if directory exists...
No directory found. Making: ./11111-1.jpg
mkdir: ./11111-1.jpg: File exists
Does the directory exist now?....Yes.

so..if [ ! -d $dir ] is looking for the dir?

Comment: The `sed` command in the pipeline is there exactly to avoid that. Are you sure you didn't miss anything? What its does, is (per input line): capture the  5 digits following `./` and output that capture.